# How to load flutter stepper steps one by one

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using built-in stepper provided by flutter but it loads all steps once when sign up screen is initiated. Is there any way to load stepper steps one by one.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: yes, you can use a `flag` to determine whether you have already done filling your form.

Comment: I'm already doing that but it loads list of steps at once when Stepper class is initialized